# iPhone 6s ios 12.3 general settings restrictions

Tags: ios

Good day, My “restrictions” folder in “general “ unable to access)
It’s disappeared in “general “ settings. In search I can see  search result as “restrictions” but unable to access this search result. Is it connected with update 12.3??? Symbol E appeared in music. I’m not sure regarding this symbol during usage 12.2. And my friend with 12.2 now has normal access to “restrictions” folder in “general” settings.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in understanding your situation and your problem.  Could you add some screenshots?

Comment: Symbol E in music stands for explicit content. To play this music you have to access “restrictions” folder and enable explicit content . Thank you for your time. I guess that is all.

Comment: `Content & Privacy Restrictions` is now under `Settings -> Screen Time`.  Check your Restrictions there.